# "Syntax error or access violation" error while trying to join a table column multiple times

Tags: php, laravel, join, laravel-5.8

I want to join 3 tables named `members`, `students` and `baseinfos`.

And baseinfos holds some `id` as `bas_id` and name of it is stored in `bas_value`:

[image]

And this is my code:

```
$records = DB::table('members')
            ->where('mys_olp_id',4)
            ->join('students', 'members.mbr_usr_id', '=', 'students.std_mbr_id')
            ->join('baseinfos as gender', 'members.mbr_gender_id', '=', 'gender.bas_id as gvalue')
            ->join('baseinfos as degree', 'students.std_degree_id', '=', 'degree.bas_id as dvalue')
            ->select('gender.gvalue', 'degree.dvalue')
            ->get()->toArray();
```

But this is wrong and shows me this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as `gvalue` inner join `baseinfos` as `degree`
```

Note that I can not say this:

```
$records = DB::table('members')
            ->where('my_students.mys_olp_id',4)
            ->join('students', 'members.mbr_usr_id', '=', 'students.std_mbr_id')
            ->join('baseinfos as degree', 'students.std_degree_id', '=', 'degree.bas_id')
            ->join('baseinfos as gender', 'members.mbr_gender_id', '=', 'gender.bas_id')
            ->select('gender.bas_value', 'degree.bas_value')
            ->get()->toArray();
```

Because `degree.bas_value` will overwrites `gender.bas_value`!

So how can I join these 3 tables properly?

Comment: What is an alias supposed to have to do inside the JOIN conditions? This belongs into the `->select()` part.

Comment: @CBroe Please would you tell me the correct coding for this

Comment: Please provide tables structure as DDL

Comment: you should provide your table .sql file and share link here. it will be easy to test and answer correctly

Comment: Look this solution: https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/a4f0d2ef5d8c602cb444947b7b1330aa/php/php8/e195656c1037da9a7f9d11b30784e9b0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your aliase inside join does not formated correctly. I think you can achieve this in this way-

```
$records = DB::table('members')
            ->join('students', 'students.std_mbr_id', '=', 'members.mbr_usr_id')
            ->join('baseinfos as gender','gender.bas_id', '=', 'members.mbr_gender_id')
            ->join('baseinfos as degree','degree.bas_id' , '=', 'students.std_degree_id')
            ->where('mys_olp_id',4)
            ->select('gender.bas_id as gvalue', 'degree.bas_id as dvalue')
            ->get();
```